# Do compilers avoid intermediate integral promotion or conversions?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, integer, compiler-optimization

Consider a class like:

```
struct mystruct 
{
    constexpr operator char() {return x;}
    signed char x;
};
```

and an operation like:

```
mystruct m;
m.x = /* something at runtime */
int i = 3 * m + 45ULL * m;
```

Are compilers able to skip the temporary conversion to `char` and convert directly `m` to the required type in the `3 * m + 45ULL * m` expression?

Comment: Compile to assembly and find out!

Comment: That depends on the compiler and flags you used. But then what if you `return x ? x * 10 : 10;`  or something more complex. I dont think compiler in general skips *intermediate* conversion to `char` because after all it is a function call, which can do a lot of complex things and so the final value may not be computed *without first knowing* the intermediate values, which also includes things like truncation due to smaller type.

Comment: The compiler implements the language rules, as best as it can. If the result doesn't match what you would deduce by applying the rules, the compiler is broken.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "Are compilers able to skip the temporary conversion to char and cast directly m to the required type in the 3 * m + 45ULL * m expression?"  ? There is no temporary conversion, `3 * m` is exactly the same as `3 * m.x` -- unless we're on a system wher eplain char is unsigned

Comment: For the 3 * m part: 3 is an int, x is a signed char. But there is not direct conversion from x to int. Is the compiler able to transform m.x into an int to make the multiplication?

Comment: `signed char` is promoted to `int` because of the integer promotions (those are the language rules for the `*` operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like GCC version 5.3.0 is able to optimize the call to cast function, while Clang 3.7 is not as smart.

For this piece of code:

```
struct mystruct 
{
    constexpr operator char() const {return x;}
    signed char x;
} m;

void func(const int num) {
  m.x = num*2;
  int i = 3 * m + 45ULL * m;
}
```

you can check compiled assembly and compare them:

[Clang with cast](https://goo.gl/sbxYml) vs [Clang with direct reference to field](https://goo.gl/7JtHvr)

[Gcc with cast](https://goo.gl/ne8bYb) vs [Gcc with direct reference to field](https://goo.gl/5dDUVh)

Though in a slightly different situation Clang does [manage to optimize](https://goo.gl/ADxlld) the call to cast function.